# Как вывести в одну строку показание введенного времени через двоеточие

Tags: java

Банальнейший вопрос, но не могу найти на него ответ. Вводим числа, что будут являться часами, минутами и секундами, как вывести в одну строку результат в таком виде: 
23:20:40
То есть используя символ двоеточие.

```
System.out.print("Введите значение H ");
    while ((h = scan.nextInt()) < 0 || h > 23) {
        System.out.println("Нужно ввести значение от 0 до 23 ");
```

Comment: вводим числа как? Приведите минимальный пример кода, в котором вы вводите числа и укажите место, где нужно добавить необходимый код.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Просто конкатенируйте строки:

```
System.out.print(h+":"+m+":"+s);
```

Comment: Так просто, спасибо большое)

Comment: А разве красиво будет выводить время в виде, например,  `7:0:5` ?

Comment: @m.vokhm некрасиво. А есть решение для этого?

Comment: @Reserveb конечно. `System.out.format("%02d:%02d:%02d\n", h, m, s);`

Comment: @m.vokhm Спасибо! )